# Swal popup - Align text and resize button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popup created using swal and the text is not aligned to the center of the modal. I have added text-align but I see that it's not exactly aligned to center a few gaps are more on the left side and I am not able to change the button size equally for both ok and cancel. Please help.

```js
swal({
  text: "Are you sure ?",
  buttons: ["Cancel", true],
})
```

```css
.swal-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.swal-modal {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't have a designer eye but that looks horizontally centered to me. I scored poorly here: https://www.supremo.co.uk/designers-eye/

Comment: For the buttons just use a fixed width. `.swal-button { width: 100px; }`

Comment: but text-align property is not working ..If i give left its still centered.This is what tricking me

Comment: Try removing the `display: inline-block` and check.

Comment: i did not add `display: inline-block`

Comment: It's there by default. Override it with block level and then try the alignment.